# Angular how to properly get class elements?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a little question about class element get from API. My class is like this;

```
export class Game {
   count:number;
   next:string;
   previous:string;
   public results = new class {
      game_id:number;
      title:string;
   }
}
```

In the ts file, I go like;

```
games: Game[] //to have a variable  called games which belongs to game class

ngOnInit() {
  
  //with the func below, I subscribe the data that comes from API
  this.gameService.getGames().subscribe(data => {
    this.games = data
  })
}
```

In html file, I need to acces the results part of the games vector, because that part is the part that I need to ngFor. Here is my html code;

```
<div *ngFor="let g of games.result"> <!-- Since the result part should be in a loop -->
    <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">{{g.title}}</h5>
       <p class="card-text">{{g.game_id}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the problem, when I run this code it works fine, I can see it on my screen (when I console.log it I can see the results part too in the console), but in the console at inspect, I get the error "property 'results' does not exist on type Game[]".

Also I cannot reach to results part of the subscribed data at my ts file, too. How can I fix these little errors?

EDIT: The JSON file that I am subscribing with the variable of 'game' is kind of something like this; (So this whole data is game and in html it says game.results is undefined, I dont know why)

```
 [
    {
    "count": 18105,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/api/games?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "game_id": 3,
            "title": "Basketball"
        },
        {
            "game_id": 8,
            "title": "Football"
        },
        //THE DATA GOES ON AND ON LIKE THIS FOR THIS PAGE
      ]
   }
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let g of games?.result">
  <!-- Since the result part should be in a 
    loop -->
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{g?.title}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{g?.game_id}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Always try to use `?` when parsing an object in HTML. This is a safe check, so you check the variable is defined before you access it.

Comment: I have tried that and it actually partially works. Now I dont get any error message at browser console, but I get some error message at visual studio code terminal tha saying: "ERROR in src/app/games/games.component.html:49:39 - error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type Game[]". But it does not compile now for some reason ://

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div *ngFor="let g of games">
    <div class="card-body">
       <div class="row" *ngFor="let r of g.results">
         <h5 class="card-title">{{r.title}}</h5>
         <p class="card-text">{{r.game_id}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or may be if you got just a game:

```
<div *ngFor="let r of games[0].results">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{r.title}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{r.game_id}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that but I then get another error about ngFor that saying it can only itterate the itterables such as arrays

Comment: Add please to your question part of this.games data which you got from server.

Comment: I have edited the question and shared the data that I am subscribing